# Trello API: Put on an Action

Tags: api, trello

I see the API allows for us to write to a user's actions with a put on an action:

PUT /1/actions/[idAction]/text

But what goes in that text? What exactly are we changing when we run this command?  Can we change any trait of an action and re-write history?

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That route is used to edit comments.  It will fail if the action provided is not a comment, or if you are not allowed to edit that comment.  The route

```
PUT /1/actions/[idAction]
```

has the same purpose.

Comment: Is there a way to edit history of an action? Or is that considered breaking an audit trail?

Comment: @DanielD Comment text is the only part of an action that can be edited.  Everything else is considered true history, and not to be changed.  (And comments that have been edited are marked as such, with a timestamp representing the most recent edit time in addition to the timestamp representing the original comment time.)